# How to calculate expected value of normal distribution with the condition that value is higher than x

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have following problem.
Let assume that lifespan in the population has normal distribution with certain mean, variance and skewness.

When the baby is born, its average lifespan will be equal to mean - this is obvious. But let's assume that the person did not die for x years and now its age is x. What is expected lifespan for this person if we know that he or she lives already x years?

How we calculated it if the distribution was e.g. Lévy stable distribution (or any other)?

Comment: "normal distribution with certain mean, variance and skewness"  The _skewness_ of a _normal_ distribution is always $0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you are asking the following question. If we know
the distribution of $Y$, what is $E(Y|Y > x).$ The fundamental
idea is to take the part of the distribution of $Y$ to the
right of $x,$ re-scale that part so that it sums (or integrates)
to unity, and then find the mean of the new conditional distribution.
Methods and results differ greatly depending on the distribution.

If $Y$ is **exponential,** then (by the no-memory property), the
conditional mean of *additional* life, starting at $x$ is the
same as the mean of the original distribution. Some electronic
devices that "die" exclusively by random accident have this
property. A used one is as good as a new one. If the device
had a 10-year expected lifetime when made, and it survives to age 5,
then its expected additional lifetime is still 10 years.
Obviously, this distribution does not apply to human lifetimes--but
neither does a normal distribution.

If $Y$ has a **uniform** distribution on $(0, 100)$ starting at 
time $0$ and survives to age $x = 40,$ then the remaining 
part of the distribution is uniform on $(40, 100).$ Its
expected lifetime is now 30 *more* years or a total of 70.

Suppose $Y$ has a **normal** distribution with mean 50 and and standard
deviation 10. (As in the Comment by @Michael Hardy, this is a symmetrical distribution with zero skewness.) Suppose we are given that $Y > 60,$ then the
remaining part of the distribution is not normal but considerably
skewed, it would require numerical methods to find the mean
of the corresponding conditional distribution. I got about 65.2, or about 5.2 additional years.

An **actual lifetime distribution** of humans typically
has a decreasing death rate over  the early months of life,
as babies survive many special hazards of newborns and
then an increasing death rate as bodies begin to wear out.
That is why most computations on actual lifetimes use life
tables based on actual data rather than theoretical distributions.
The principle is the same, but you would have to look at the
life table for specifics. Many life tables include projections
for additional years of life at each age. (In practice, human lifetime
distributions are *not* exponential, uniform, or normal.)

*Addendum:* Below are simple simulations in R, each based
on a million cases, illustrating the statements above about
exponential, uniform, and normal distributions. The method
is not optimal, but very easy to program and adequate for
present purposes. Accuracy is to the nearest integer, maybe
a little more.

```
 # Exponential
 y1 = rexp(10^6, 1/10)  # death rate 1/10 per year
 mean(y1)
 ## 10.00546  # check that original mean is 10
 mean(y1[y1 > 5])  # survives to age 5
 ## 15.01287  # conditional mean 15;  10 years additional life

 # Uniform
 y2 = runif(10^6, 0,  100)
 mean(y2)
 ##  49.95337 # check that original mean is 50
 mean(y2[y2 > 40])  # survives to age 40
 ## 70.00422  # conditional mean 70,  30 years additional life

 # Normal  
 y3 = rnorm(10^6, 50, 10)
 mean(y3)
 ## 50.01684  # check that original mean is 50
 mean(y3[y3>60])  # survives to age 60
 ## 65.26052  # conditioal mean 65.2.  5.2 years additional life
```